# How do I add a menu task to /node path?

Tags: routes, 8

I want to add a custom tab after "Edit" but can't figure out how to do so. I added a mymodule.links.task.yml file

```
entity.node.import_form:
  route_name: entity.node.import_form
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: Import JSON from file
```

But I don't understand what to do next. The node form just errors out with:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException:
>   Route "entity.node.import_form" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()
>   (line 128 of /var/www/sites/datacenter.com/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

Comment: Do you have defined entity.node.import_form in your $module.routing.yml file?

Comment: I think I got confused looking at how Node adds an edit tab. I did not have a routing file, instead I looked at the node route provider class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is to create a menu task on the route `entity.node.canonical` with the title of `Import JSON from file` which links to the route `entity.node.import_form`.

The error you are getting is because the route `entity.node.import_form` (the link of the task) doesn't exist. You have to either depend/enable the module that provides this route or create the route yourself.

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing information or a link on  how to   _create the route yourself_ as mymodule.links.task.yml would seem to be his attempt to create the route himself.